# How to extract a string from URL in Swift 3?

Tags: string, url, swift3

I have a URL of a YouTube video. Now, I need to extract a string and save it to a variable. Here, I need to extract videoid from the URL. The link is:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTcq6L-PaDQ

Now, I need to extract `iTcq6L-PaDQ` in Swift 3.

Comment: String("your URL")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

You can get Video ID as substring from String Url like below.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTcq6L-PaDQ" )!.absoluteString

let Id = url.substring(from: url.range(of: "?v=")!.upperBound)
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern solution with `URLComponents / URLQueryItem`

```
if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTcq6L-PaDQ"),
    let queryItem = urlComponents.queryItems?.first(where: {$0.name == "v"}) {
    print(queryItem.value!)
}
```

or as function

```
func queryValue(for name : String, of url: URL) -> String?
{
    guard let urlComponents = URLComponents(url:url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL:false),
        let queryItem = urlComponents.queryItems?.first(where: {$0.name == name}) else { return nil }
    return queryItem.value
}

queryValue(for: "v", of: URL(string:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTcq6L-PaDQ")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this example

```
let url = ___Your_URL_HERE____
let path = String(contentsOf: url)
let startIndex = path.index(path.startIndex, offsetBy: 32) //32 because 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' is fixed from youtube
let videoid = path.substring(from: startIndex)
print(videoid)
```

Comment: It shows error as "value of type 'URL' has no member 'index' ". How can I solve this issue ? @ Umesh Verma

Comment: if you have url then convert it to string first. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the url string by **"?v="** which is common for any youtube video.

```
let path = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTcq6L-PaDQ")
let url = path!.absoluteString
let array = url.components(separatedBy: "?v=")
let id = array[1]
NSLog("video id: %@.", id)
```

Comment: It shows error as "value of type 'URL' has no member "components ". How can I solve this issue ? @ Rahul Kumar

Comment: convert URL type to String, using URL.absoluteString, you can get as String type